# Can any byte array be converted to a string?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, arrays

Can any byte array be converted to a string? Or there are some byte values that are not available or cannot be converted to characteres depending on the encoding of the string?

Comment: Not entirely serious, but I have created a method that will convert ***any*** byte array to a string: `static string GetString(byte[] arr)
        {
            return string.Join(" - ", arr.Select(b => string.Join("-", Enumerable.Range(1, 8).Select(x => (b & 1 << 8 - x) == 0 ? '0' : '1'))));
        }` Copy-paste the method to try it out.

Comment: Not what I was thinking of, but it's an alternative XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only try to convert byte arrays to strings if they *started* as text. If the byte array is actually the contents of an image file, or a video, or maybe encoded or compressed data, you should *not* try to convert it straight to a string using an encoding. Doing so almost always goes badly in the end: with ISO-8859-1 you *might* be okay, but it's fundamentally a bad idea, and you really shouldn't do it.

Instead, you should use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) to convert it to [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), or perhaps convert it to hex instead.

If you do use Base64, you'd use [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) to convert back from text to a byte array.

Answer (score 2):

> Can any byte array be converted to a string?

[`Base64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) seems like an appropriate representation of a byte array:

```
byte[] buffer = ...
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

In .NET you could use the [`ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) method to achieve this.

Also you seem to have talked about some *encoding of a string* in your question, but in .NET all strings are UTF-16 encoded, so I don't quite understand what you meant by that.

Comment: Thanks @Darin Dimitrov, I was thinking of the way the bytes will be interpreted during the conversion: ANSI, UTF-8, etc. I'm not sure, but I think the enconding used during the conversion to string may alter the result.

Comment: @guillegr123, there's absolutely no encoding involved when you are converting a byte array to Base64. By definition, if you have a byte array, this byte array is already encoded using some encoding. So, there's no altering possible whatsoever during this process. The byte array represented by the Base64 string will keep all the information it had initially.

Answer (score 0):

Strings may be converted into sequences of bytes using a variety of encodings.  Some encodings can convert any possible string to some sequence of bytes; others will only work with strings containing a limited variety of characters, but for every possible byte sequence there will exist a string that would yield it.  Some encoding methods will convert any possible string into an even-length sequence of bytes, and will allow any even-length sequence of bytes to be converted back to a string, but cannot yield odd-length strings.  I'm not aware of any encoding methods which create a one-to-one relationship between all possible strings and all possible arbitrary-length byte sequences.

Once upon a time, strings were a convenient way of holding arbitrary byte sequences, but in .NET they may only be used as a means of holding binary data if the data is filtered so as to ensure that it doesn't contain any invalid characters or sequences.  I wish there was an "immutable byte sequence" type which could be used for that purpose which used to be served by strings, but I'm unaware of one.